# How to resize all row of a column?

Tags: libreoffice

Suppose you are researching on a topic and have found something with a tabular form, now you would like to save that in your spreadsheet application to see that when offline, so you fired up OpenOffice Calc or MS Excel and pasted that table.

Now I don't know about MS Excel, but when I pasted in LibreOffice Calc then I seen something like as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Uneven Row Size]

As you can see the ***width*** of column A B and C can be resized because they are only 3 in numbers, but its hard to edit **the *height* of 1, 2, 3, 4 etc**.

### Question

Any other way to resize the heights of 1, 2, 3, 4 than doing manually?

Comment: can you upload a stripped down copy of the libreoffice file in question to sendspace?  i think i have a solution, but i need to test it

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/67349120/PHP%20Reference.xls

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open the file.

<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to select all.

Either:
**A**
Format -> Row -> Optimal Height
OK

**B**
Format -> Row -> Height
Set a height.
*You could find the desired height by doing this same thing on the largest row and checking the value*

Answer (score 5):

LibreOffice Calc will automatically resize the height. In your case all the results were just enough for a single line.

You might need to wrap around a column. In order to do this.

Basing from your screenshot.

1. Resize column B in such that it has smaller width (desired width).
2. Set your selection tool to the column header (column B). You should select the entire column.
3. Right click it and format cells.
4. Go to Format Cells -> Alignment -> check wrap text automatically.

There you go. All entries that are wider enough to the desire width will be automatically wrapped. Once wrapped the LibreOffice Calc will automatically adjust it's height.

Added: If row height needs to be of the same height.

If you want to make your row height of the same height.

1. Select the rows (header, the one that has number).

[image]

2. Put your selection in between the separator of each row number.

[image]

3. Drag it and set the desired height.

[image]